Why don't folders delete in gulp tasks?
This task work ok. I use path ".wwwroot/css/site.min.css"
var gulp = require("gulp");
const fs = require('fs').promises;

gulp.task('clean', async function (done) {
    try {
        await fs.rm(".wwwroot/js/temp/site.min.js", { recursive: true, force: true });
        done();
    } catch (error) {
        done(error);
    }
});

But if I use path '.wwwroot/js/temp/'. I get error:
The following tasks did not complete: clean
Did you forget to signal async completion?
"npm": "10.8.2",
"node": "20.17.0"
The problem appeared after I decided to update to rimraf 2.2.8. It was suggested to use the built-in fs library

async function removeTempFolder(done) {
    const dirPath = 'wwwroot/js/temp/';

    try {
        const files = await fs.readdir(dirPath);

        if (!files || files.length === 0) {
            console.log('No files to delete.');
        } else {
            for (const file of files) {
                const filePath = path.join(dirPath, file);
                await fs.unlink(filePath);
                console.log(`Deleted file: ${filePath}`);
            }
        }

        await fs.rm(dirPath, { recursive: true, force: true });
        console.log('Directory deleted successfully');
        done();
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
            console.log('Directory does not exist:', dirPath);
        } else {
            console.error('Error deleting files or directory:', err);
        }
        done(err);
    }
}

